# Why does That code returning 10 instead of 5?

Tags: javascript, syntax, whitespace

why the syntax parser wont inject a semicolon in var after carriage return but in function t the return got injected ?

```
var a = 5
+
5
console.log(a); //results 10

function t(){
 return
 5
}

console.log(t()); //results undefined
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 1):

Expressions in JavaScript do not end at the end of the line. That's where semicolons are important. `return` is a complete statement on its own and has automatic semicolon insertion.